# How to custom position row table?

Tags: html, css

I want to customise my table row position like the image below. The table header should be aligned at same level but the elements inside should look like the image below.

[image]

Here's my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Destination</th>
    <th>Speed</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Destination 1</td>
    <td rowspan="1">5.0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Destination 2</td>
        <td rowspan="1">5.0</td>

  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Destination 3</td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: share what you have done till.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/vzCPWNxp

Comment: like that? - https://ibb.co/jT613Hn

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov yes sir, can you provide the code?

Comment: @dedyrizaldi, I made your decision. Check, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
td:not(:first-of-type) {
   position: relative;
   transform: translateY(50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Destination</th>
    <th>Speed</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Destination 1</td>
    <td rowspan="1">5.0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Destination 2</td>
        <td rowspan="1">5.0</td>
 
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Destination 3</td>
  </tr>
 
</tbody>
</table>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was glad to help, bro :)